# When you take damage that causes bleed but the initial damage only affects temporary HP, do you actually gain the bleed condition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, temporary-hit-points

When you take damage that causes bleed but the initial damage only affects temporary HP, do you actually gain the bleed condition when you haven't lost any HP? I ask because injury poison does not work when it causes no damage due to DR, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any effect contingent upon hit point loss is triggered by the loss of temporary hit points. [Temporary Hit Points](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Temporary-Hit-Points) says that they are

> in addition to the character’s current hit point total and any damage taken by the character is subtracted from these hit points first. Any damage in excess of a character’s temporary hit points is applied to his current hit points as normal. If the effect that grants the temporary hit points ends or is dispelled, any remaining temporary hit points go away. The damage they sustained is not transferred to the character’s current hit points.

…And that's pretty much the entire difference between a creature's hit points and temporary hit points.

There's no rules connection between temporary hit points (that are lost like normal hit points) and [damage reduction](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction) (that can prevent hit point damage from being dealt, whether as a whole or in part).

Comment: That last line from the description is kind of my point, the damage is not transfered, so the bleed damage was only applied to the temp HP

Comment: @Fering It doesn't matter that the hit points were real or temporary; if an effect needs to deal hp damage to have an effect, and it deals hit point damage, then it'll have an effect, whether or not the hit point damage it dealt was to temporary hit points, normal hit points, or a combination of the two. *You* care that they're temporary hit points; *the effect* only cares that they were hit points.

Comment: This is accurate... and can be reconfirmed by the special exception of the Oracle ability [Shell of Succor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/succor/)